# How to correct a db schema?

Tags: lookup, design

I have problem in a Salesforce db schema.  The relevant part of the schema looks like this:

1. Program
2. State
3. District
4. Site
5. Scholar

All are custom objects and each is related (lookup field) to the one above it on the list.   Scholar is also currently related to State. Scholar should have been related to District, but it was not created as intended (long story).

Certain kinds of reporting would be easier if this error could be corrected.  How can I do this without breaking my db?  Obviously, I'd want to give any solution a trial run in a sandbox, but here's what I've been thinking about doing.

1. Add the new relationship to District to Scholar
2. Fill in the new relationship via Demand Tools
3. Adjust existing Apex code to use the new relationship
4. Fix reports and report types to use the new relationship
5. Remove the old relationship to State from Scholar

Step 4 involves finding the related reports and report types.  Using Eclipse to find reports and report types that will need updating is what I've come up with.  As far as I know, the reports created from the implicit (system created) report types will simply break and need to be re-created.

Step 5 might not be strictly necessary.  Scholar has a lot of lookups already.  Not increasing the number will help prevent performance problems.  On the other hand, skipping it would avoid the breakage of reports mentioned previously.

Is there a better way to do any of this?  Am I missing anything?

Comment: Changing relationships and having them reflected in reports will always be a challenge.  I can't think of any streamlined way of doing this.  Looking at your schema though, my first question is, why do you have so many objects?  To me, the State, District, and Site objects all sound like part of an address.  I obviously don't know all the thought behind this, but it feels like you could simplify your schema which would make reporting easier.  Why would picklists and/or an Address field not achieve a similar outcome?

Comment: I may have oversimplified here.  I wanted to give a succinct example of what I need to change without our potentially confusing internal terminology.  What I am calling a State and District here represent, respectively, a specific state's and district's participation in one program.